# Where to find hardware for awning mount?

Tags: process

I'm looking into building an awning, but having trouble locating some of the materials. Where would I find the hardware in the picture below? I need a somewhat decorative piece of metal to mount the awning to the wall.

I also thought I would be able to find plans for building an awning like the one pictured. Is there a good resource for finding plans for woodworking projects, or do I just need to put in the work to create one myself?

[image: Awning mount]

Comment: Just to clarify, you're talking about just the screws/bolts, but the entire wrought iron-looking curvy thingamabobber, right?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the wrought iron-looking curvy thingamabobber. I had no idea how to go about finding one or what kind of shop would make them. I'm going to try to find a local blacksmith to see if they can whip something up for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about acquiring specific pieces of hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a custom job to me.  Thought it doesn't look to hard to copy.  The hardware also looks like it could be custom made.

The awning has three boards on the bottom, then the pergola boards across.  Then one board on each end of the pergola boards to 'hide' the ends. Last a board across the front to hide the ends and make it look like solid squares on the ends.

With just one screw holding into the brick, I would guess that most of what holds it securely to the wall is at the top end.

Comment: tl;dr find a blacksmith to do the work. Either way it looks cantilevered to me.

Comment: I would agree that the scrolls look to wimpy to be supporting much weight. I'd venture that the top is quite firmly attached to the brick. It's hard to be sure, but at the far end it looks like it's actually inserted into a notch in the brick wall, possibly bolted/nailed to the wood frame of the house for support.

Comment: Thanks for all the info everybody! This particular awning is mounted at the top with what looks like a type of hinge. I was having a hard time finding out how to locate the hardware, but I'll check around for a blacksmith to look into getting something custom made.